# Simple PHP result message with some other points

Tags: php, html

**Html Code (index.html)**

```
<div id="stable" class="center-div" >
    <form method="POST" action="send.php">
        <input type="text" name="FNAME" value="FIRST NAME" size="20" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">

        <!--<input type="text" name="LNAME" value="LAST NAME" size="20" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">-->


        <input type="text" name="Email" VALUE="EMAIL" size="20" style="font-size:13px; height:50px; background-color:#f5f5f5"onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" class="button">

    </div>
</form>
```

**Php code (send.php)**

```
<?php

## CONFIG ##

# LIST EMAIL ADDRESS
$recipient = "admin@gmail.com";

# SUBJECT (Subscribe/Remove)
$subject = "Someone wants updates!";

# RESULT PAGE
$location = "index.html";

## FORM VALUES ##

# SENDER - WE ALSO USE THE RECIPIENT AS SENDER IN THIS SAMPLE
# DON'T INCLUDE UNFILTERED USER INPUT IN THE MAIL HEADER!S
$sender = $recipient;

# MAIL BODY
$body .= "Name: ".$_REQUEST['FNAME']." \n";

$body .= "Email: ".$_REQUEST['Email']." \n";
# add more fields here if required

## SEND MESSGAE ##

mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, "From: $sender" ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");

## SHOW RESULT PAGE ##

header( "Location: $location" );
?>
```

- I want to display a thank you message once the person has
  successfully filled in the form
- I want to check for correct email id eg. if "@" and ".com" has been entered
- would it be possible to save the entries to another php or text file ? after the email has been sent ?

Thanks in advance for all replies!

Comment: *"i figured how to put the thank you message on the new page, but i need it to reflect on the same page itself , is it possible to run the php code on the same page as the html ? – user3690908 2 hours ago"* - Yes it is possible. As for your other questions, your question is too broad. In a nutshell; yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a redirect once the mail is sent. Can you place your thank you message on this page? Sometimes I have a thank you.php page for this purpose.

Here is a snippet from a contact form to check for email validation will this help?

```
if(trim($_POST['email']) === '') {
} else if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
     $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
     $hasError = true;
} else {
     $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}
```

You could save the entries a database once submitted? Or I think you can create a session to keep hold of the variables for further use. What are you planning to do with the data then after it has been submitted?

Comment: i figured how to put the thank you message on the new page, but i need it to reflect on the same page itself , is it possible to run the php code on the same page as the html ?

Comment: Yes. I do this often. Is it for error purposes? (such as missing fields) ? Just use <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> which will process the php on the same page once the form is submitted. You can then use an if statement to check if the form is sent and echo an error message to the user. Am I on the right lines?